# Null Reference when calling an internal void function inside a class from controller ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am looking for a savior to this my problem.

I am trying to follow this tutorial about Nested Collection:

[Nested collection in MVC add multiple phone number](http://www.itorian.com/2013/04/nested-collection-models-in-mvc-to-add.html)

Nevertheless, I ran into a problem with this:

```
internal void CreatePart(int count = 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            Parts.Add(new Part()); // ====>>>>>> it throws null reference
        }
    }
```

I could not find the source of the null. Can you please spot it for me?

here is my codes:

entity for product

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Part> Parts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Version> Versions { get; set; }

    internal void CreatePart(int count = 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            Parts.Add(new Part());
        }
    }
}
```

entity for parts

```
public class Part
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    public string DeletePart { get; set; }
}
```

Create controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var product = new Product();
        product.CreatePart(2);
        return View(product);
    }
```

Comment: product.Parts property is null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't actually instantiated `Parts`, so you get an exception when trying to add elements to it.

If you look at the example you linked to, you're missing a constructor in your `Product` class.

Try adding this to your class:

```
public Product()
{
    this.Parts = new HashSet<Part>();
}
```

Comment: Just for my learning, can anybody pls explain what does HashSet mean?

Comment: Mr Grant, too bad your website is down. Should you in any way come to Indonesia, I will gladly assist you here.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure on this but!

Change this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
   Parts.Add(new Part());
}
```

To this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
   Part p = new Part(); 
   Parts.Add(p);
}
```

If the error is now moved to:

`Part p = new Part();` << Here

Then I guess the problem is how it is getting initialised.

Could you try defining a constructor for the Part class and give it dummy values see what happens then.